# How to find a folder on my server with a certain name?

Tags: command-line, directory, find

I have a directory somewhere on my server wth the name "exampledocs". I tried to find it's location using:

```
ls -d */ | grep -E 'exampledocs'
```

and

```
find * -regextype posix-extended \-regex 'exampledocs' \-type d
```

and

```
grep "exampledocs" * --recursive
```

Nothing worked. How can I do this from the command line? I'm using Ubuntu Server 11.0.

Answer (score 76, accepted):

```
find / -xdev 2>/dev/null -name "exampledocs"
```

Note: This is from Debian, but it should work.

Answer (score 95):

This also should work

```
find folder_full_path -name exampledocs -type d
```

Comment: its find-out from whole computer.

Comment: @AmitabhaBiswas you need to set path instead of "/" in the command to search in specific folder.

Comment: find /path/to/search/ -name exampledocs -type d

Answer (score 8):

`locate exampledocs | grep /exampledocs$`

Answer (score 0):

With `bash`'s `globstar` shell option and `[[` evaluation, we can make use of recursive globbing and prefix removal to find directories that contain the needed string. Here's how I'd search for `bin` folder:

```
bash-4.3$ shopt -s globstar
bash-4.3$ for f in ./**/* ; do [ -d "$f" ] && [[ "${f##*/}" =~ ^bin$ ]] && echo "$f" ; done
./bin
./Desktop/TODAY/bin
```